# I love you too, like actually”

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, american-english

[image]

Can somebody explain me the meaning, in this particular case, of “like, actually”?

Comment: As in “you might have thought I was just being cute in my first text with all the emojis. So I wanted to clarify that I really do...”

Comment: Emphatic like strikes again!

Comment: "Like, actually" is a slangy way to say "For real"—that is, "I'm using a very common phrase ('I love you, too') that many people use whether they mean it or not, but I really really mean it."

Answer (score -2):

The person who texted Sofia, actually loves Sofia.

Comment: (At least that's what they're saying)

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the context it may also be the case that the other person is trying to indicate they meant to convey they *like*, instead of *love*, Sofia.

If, as other suggested, they meant to emphasise the aforementioned *love*, they would (this is speculation) probably say something along the lines of: *I really do*, rather than using the word *actually*.